# Como poderia disparar uma ação em um script em PHP com um link?

Tags: php, mysql, script

Como poderia disparar uma ação em um script em PHP a partir de um link?

```
<ul class="categorias">
    <li><a href="">Lançamentos</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Vista Panorâmica</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Mobiliados</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Pronto para Morar</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Usados</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Duplex</a></li>
</ul>
```

Eu já tenho um script pronto que deve receber esse valor por `$_GET`. Teria como eu usar o elemento html `<a>` para disparar esta ação no script `PHP` com um valor transferido por `$_GET`? Consigo fazer com jQuery e também por formulários mas gostaria de tentar fazer por PHP.

Comment: Tentou passar o arquivo e a querystring no link, `<a href="principal/lancamento.php?id=1&nome=teste">Lançamentos</a>`

Comment: if ($_GET['name_sua_var']) { comandos;}

Comment: @perdeu foi mais um branco que outra coisa. Pode formular uma resposta para que eu avalie? Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou fazer com base nas informações que você passou no seu código, acredito que você esteja fazendo um sistema para aluguel/ venda de imóveis, é o seguinte:

No atributo **href** dos links [***a***] da sua lista você pode fazer "*http://nomeDoSeuSite.com.br/scriptQueRecebeParametros.php?categoria=nomeDaCategoria*", neste caso o parâmetro **categoria** pode receber um ID do banco de dados ou até mesmo um nome.

Para o arquivo **index.php**:

```
<ul class="categorias">
    <li><a href="http://nomeDoSeuSite.com.br/scriptQueRecebeParametros.php?categoria=lancamentos">Lançamentos</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://nomeDoSeuSite.com.br/scriptQueRecebeParametros.php?categoria=vista_panoramicas">Vista Panorâmica</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://nomeDoSeuSite.com.br/scriptQueRecebeParametros.php?categoria=mobiliados">Mobiliados</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://nomeDoSeuSite.com.br/scriptQueRecebeParametros.php?categoria=pronto_morar">Pronto para Morar</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://nomeDoSeuSite.com.br/scriptQueRecebeParametros.php?categoria=usados">Usados</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://nomeDoSeuSite.com.br/scriptQueRecebeParametros.php?categoria=duplex">Duplex</a></li>
```

No arquivo **scriptQueRecebeParametros.php**, faz o seguinte:

```
<?php
/**
 * $categoria
 * É a variável que receberá as informações da página principal.
 * 
 * Vamos fazer por $_REQUEST, pois desta forma se seu script mudar no futuro e você
 * resolver passar os parâmetros via $_POST ou qualquer tipo de método HTTP,
 * o script de recebimento não irá parar de funcionar. Desta forma primeiro
 * verificamos se o valor foi passado com "isset", caso tenha vindo recebe o valor,
 * caso contrário recebe vazio
 */

$categoria = isset($_REQUEST['categoria']) ? $_REQUEST['categoria'] : '';

// Se código aqui!
```